# Cómo llamar a un JInternal

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi proyecto, estoy trabajando con java en NetBeans, creé un FrameForm y otros internal, y a la hora de llamarlos con el DesktopPane.add, me da error en el add y dice que no puede encontrar el símbolo, alguien aquí sabe a que se deba?